# Python random.choices() doesn't give desired output

Tags: python, random

I'm having trouble getting a correct output using `random.choices()`

```py
population
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121, 122, 123, 124, 125, 126, 127, 128, 129, 130, 131, 132, 133, 134, 135, 136, 137, 138, 139, 140, 141, 142, 143, 144, 145, 146, 147, 148, 149, 150, 151, 152, 153, 154, 155, 156, 157, 158, 159, 160, 161, 162, 163, 164, 165, 166, 167, 168, 169, 170, 171, 172, 173, 174, 175, 176, 177, 178, 179, 180, 181, 182, 183, 184, 185, 186, 187, 188, 189, 190, 191, 192, 193, 194, 195, 196, 197, 198, 199, 200, 201, 202, 203, 204, 205, 206, 207, 208, 209, 210, 211, 212, 213, 214, 215, 216, 217, 218, 219, 220, 221, 222, 223, 224, 225, 226, 227, 228, 229, 230, 231, 232, 233, 234, 235, 236, 237, 238, 239, 240, 241, 242, 243, 244, 245, 246, 247, 248, 249, 250, 251, 252, 253, 254, 255, 256, 257, 258, 259, 260, 261, 262, 263, 264, 265, 266, 267, 268, 269, 270, 271, 272, 273, 274, 275, 276, 277, 278, 279, 280, 281, 282, 283, 284, 285, 286, 287, 288, 289, 290, 291, 292, 293, 294, 295, 296, 297, 298, 299, 300, 301, 302, 303, 304, 305, 306, 307, 308, 309, 310, 311, 312, 313, 314, 315, 316, 317, 318, 319, 320, 321, 322, 323, 324, 325, 326, 327, 328, 329, 330, 331, 332, 333, 334, 335, 336, 337, 338, 339, 340, 341, 342, 343, 344, 345, 346, 347, 348, 349, 350, 351, 352, 353, 354, 355, 356, 357, 358, 359, 360, 361, 362, 363, 364, 365, 366, 367, 368, 369, 370, 371, 372, 373, 374, 375, 376, 377, 378, 379, 380, 381, 382, 383, 384, 385, 386, 387, 388, 389, 390, 391, 392, 393, 394, 395, 396, 397, 398, 399, 400]
weights
[51.405730314615, 34.038561930089, 25.305256247942495, 23.421442399705697, 11.832851217393099, 30.724656363159, 18.293965334941106, 25.135883277376905, 19.262360230921203, 35.229190152857996, 36.285737522933005, 10.828243123380503, -70.0, 16.514199402858495, 22.1320507694671, 26.2100470473426, 10.093096012912497, 39.070903089438005, 38.643392724147006, 10.931176452988097, 21.467519156139602, 13.4727705081214, 44.829696469886, 28.364788435402303, 11.640821295354002, 18.389909447076803, 24.775447690318998, 12.020813180938106, 36.02379898698101, 11.4259511348194, 23.494130975552693, -70.0, 23.352356491031102, 21.167638775879894, 18.391994159771897, 17.5131964086346, 26.8302986494585, 30.646021044356004, 30.189744755028997, 22.2357153950055, 20.117979662193093, 25.812759030997896, 16.981671806990605, 17.393400930605395, 34.392589570008994, 17.8947151534626, 16.626748675186505, 16.728451250826296, 20.3411653821952, 30.637490226696002, 16.754819848546006, 18.507029350666997, 21.2269644988221, -70.0, 29.2876565885243, 30.200483333760005, 33.739494064141994, 17.028866154100996, 20.006898543021407, 30.375107907559993, 28.162918332888097, 20.5652891572511, 31.026604257898, 15.999925845762206, 26.342496209871, 37.260633855479995, 34.478274695322995, 20.718582108942798, 17.012824312042994, 14.064990045515103, 27.583447521610097, 19.821231449958802, 27.344605450934196, 21.073098384869397, 26.382664658927695, 10.345807754192705, 13.373016045452204, 37.008827280833, 19.667926594788796, 20.604416044368904, 14.495727213224995, -70.0, 26.229845479225702, 37.062917886749005, 36.42878884254, 17.595513363128205, 14.996800819704603, 22.491420951515707, 31.455791520003004, 15.7080243470688, 16.8372359864085, 16.361811854335997, -70.0, 42.090178679689004, 22.5498053303334, 12.5137184681398, 11.465974817410896, 11.553030328069696, 22.698227951460098, 17.370037986357204, 17.7983572109913, -70.0, 14.591136229796206, -70.0, 12.825864782068393, 21.240500507480704, -70.0, 10.499264869906199, -70.0, 20.026214471528704, 21.3349897699472, -70.0, 16.6139102199498, 10.540745012902406, -70.0, 13.562905925135695, 26.963873474726597, 11.3699841033267, 28.495658752527106, 10.356079268683004, 23.965809957419907, 24.9533456136339, 22.262506870004003, 13.059265949411696, 26.363638455322302, 30.956151826129997, 12.050479881491597, 16.352742366749993, 20.9436410934032, 14.3174696043245, -70.0, -70.0, -70.0, 24.177434952890593, 21.106339141307302, 16.1904686844301, 22.0656483891959, 24.437186131904795, -70.0, 13.769926751218705, -70.0, 25.0642085551888, -70.0, -70.0, -70.0, 16.1044142364117, -70.0, 38.536896214151994, 13.224804773888806, 12.997246927108606, -70.0, 15.147380491118199, 24.3830379366906, -70.0, 15.211023046170993, -70.0, 20.269901263686506, 22.779555497161297, 19.6575989337465, -70.0, -70.0, -70.0, -70.0, 33.328811457342, -70.0, 35.95726774933, 11.511528200491696, -70.0, 13.729931449460295, 10.331731401591895, 20.5313505888288, 23.3330590374854, -70.0, -70.0, 11.730416631461907, 15.241306457253899, 27.915390530805197, 30.532800080027997, -70.0, -70.0, 21.626828076184196, -70.0, 13.063125354250701, 12.204532645632199, -70.0, 21.560440579014497, 19.949411988513504, 17.002298564287898, 13.531281255251699, 13.773571172124505, 28.7642145531412, 12.632392514624001, 15.6795549238781, 25.809395157906394, -70.0, 26.100243732480493, -70.0, 11.172313979731697, 18.9757683142346, -70.0, -70.0, -70.0, -70.0, -70.0, -70.0, 18.124762621560905, -70.0, -70.0, -70.0, -70.0, 17.036675894892298, -70.0, -70.0, 15.278531485158496, -70.0, -70.0, -70.0, -70.0, -70.0, 10.502399566864995, -70.0, -70.0, -70.0, -70.0, -70.0, 15.133406717495802, -70.0, 15.939594645450498, 11.059342712910706, -70.0, -70.0, -70.0, -70.0, -70.0, -70.0, -70.0, -70.0, -70.0, -70.0, 27.148056980010296, -70.0, 11.976135295162607, -70.0, -70.0, 13.132256702605503, -70.0, -70.0, -70.0, 20.169099458886294, -70.0, -70.0, -70.0, -70.0, -70.0, -70.0, -70.0, -70.0, 28.525865613710096, -70.0, 16.394395885002794, -70.0, 10.8363856700106, -70.0, -70.0, -70.0, 17.595542557705997, 15.969294415018695, -70.0, -70.0, 18.860628843479006, -70.0, -70.0, -70.0, -70.0, -70.0, -70.0, 16.287932086678296, -70.0, -70.0, -70.0, 11.045088932254899, -70.0, -70.0, -70.0, -70.0, -70.0, 21.818140556961893, -70.0, 20.118993086891805, -70.0, -70.0, 10.104447589137195, -70.0, 15.269080079551202, 21.057375430633996, 10.893072084542297, 22.699924658622905, -70.0, 11.950507050235501, 11.633926704010307, -70.0, -70.0, -70.0, -70.0, -70.0, -70.0, -70.0, -70.0, -70.0, 10.292614267767703, -70.0, -70.0, -70.0, -70.0, -70.0, -70.0, 10.075025889515004, 14.639135115265404, -70.0, -70.0, -70.0, -70.0, -70.0, -70.0, 14.245543411033097, -70.0, -70.0, -70.0, -70.0, -70.0, -70.0, -70.0, 14.074039694918696, -70.0, -70.0, 17.986344895268402, -70.0, 32.570219078817004, -70.0, 10.156370392661003, -70.0, 12.236742250165094, 13.264126224741602, -70.0, -70.0, -70.0, -70.0, -70.0, -70.0, -70.0, -70.0, -70.0, -70.0, -70.0, 11.0959906307517, 10.796488796077298, -70.0, -70.0, -70.0, -70.0, -70.0, -70.0, 16.6336964103332, -70.0, 10.105726263706998, -70.0, -70.0, -70.0, -70.0, -70.0, -70.0, -70.0, -70.0, -70.0, -70.0, -70.0, -70.0, -70.0, -70.0, -70.0, -70.0, -70.0, -70.0, -70.0, -70.0, -70.0, -70.0, 10.950452540073002, -70.0, 13.112794825696099, -70.0, -70.0, -70.0, 10.626519507381104, -70.0, -70.0, -70.0, -70.0, -70.0, 15.4536101387163]
random.choices(population,weights, k=20)
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

Why do I only get 1's?

Comment: *Minimal* examples, please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices):

> Weights are assumed to be non-negative.

Try zero-ing the negative values:

```
weights = [max(w,0) for w in weights]
```

Comment: Aha! This is probably the culprit. I did try a toy example that had a negative value and it still seemed to work, so figured I was okay.

Answer (score -1):

You've got negative numbers in the weights list. Weights are assumed to be non-negative, so that seems to be your problem. I've tinkered around with a smaller version and, yes, that's it.